# Getting info from the links that were scraped

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to get links of the book at first and then get into that link and grab the title of the book. At the end, I want to store titles in a column and links in another column in csv file. This is how I write the book. I only get links not titles.

```
import scrapy


class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_bc_3?ie=UTF8&node=468216&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%212349030011%2Cn%3A465600%2C']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"]/@href').extract()

        for link in links:
            yield {'Book Urls': link}
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.book_title)

    def book_title(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield {'Title': title}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with `response.meta`.

```
import scrapy
class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_bc_3?ie=UTF8&node=468216&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%212349030011%2Cn%3A465600%2C']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            title = response.meta.get('title')
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.book_title, meta = {'title':title, 'Link': link})


    def book_title(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract()
        response.meta['title'] = title
        yield response.meta
```